# Wrong opacity in pngs converted from svg using CairoSVG

Tags: python, svg, png, cairo, fusioncharts

We're using CairoSVG (http://cairosvg.org/) to convert svg string data into a png and return the png to the browser.  The svg string comes directly from the getSVGString() method of our FusionCharts charts.

If I save this string as an svg file locally and open it in either Illustrator or a browser, it looks fine.  Here is the svg data:  http://pastebin.com/GG0vqWF4

Here is what the image is supposed to look like: http://pbrd.co/1nE9y11

But in the png returned to the browser, all the circles are empty:  http://pbrd.co/1nE9IFL

Here's Python code that does the conversion:

```
import cherrypy
import cairocffi as cairo
import cairosvg
...

class SaveImagePage(LoggedInPage):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self, svgString, **params):
        png = cairosvg.svg2png(svgString)

        cherrypy.response.headers['content-type'] = 'image/png'
        cherrypy.response.headers['content-disposition'] = \
            'attachment; filename="BrandIndex Chart.png"'

        return png
```

Any ideas?  I haven't worked with the svg format much, and Cairo isn't throwing any errors; not sure what might be going wrong here.

Comment: I think chances are good that you are hitting a bug in CairoSVG.  Have you tried contacting them?

Comment: I hadn't, but that's a good idea; I'll do this.

Comment: @jp42 Is your issue resolved?

Comment: The issue is still present in cairosvg.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an issue with CairoSVG.

As far as specifics of the issue you are facing is concerned, earlier versions of FusionCharts( < 3.4) had a problem in the %,: characters in the  SVG string being generated. The latest version of FusionCharts rectified that problem and the generated SVG is not problematic when used for exporting in Inkscape, Batik libraries.

I've replaced the problematic %,: on the SVG string you have shared and exported using Inkscape and Cairo. On Inkscape the exported image is correct, while the problem still exists in Cairo.

**If you are open to use other export libraries, use Inkscape.But FusionCharts also has its own export functionality, If you want the exported png to be downloaded on the browser, using FusionCharts export functionality should serve the purpose.**

Comment: How did you replace the problematic character?